# Startup nomount - oracle 10 centos linux

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i got problem with starting up instance oracle 10.2.0.1 on Centos OS 
im login on root 
su - oracle 
export $ORACLE_HOME
export $ORACLE_SID

login on sqlplus / as sysdba

{SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon May 13 08:09:23 2019

Connected to an idle instance.}

startup nomount

and have ORA

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [keltnfy-ldmInit], [46], [1], [], [], [], [], []

i have created initXE.ora

lstrctl status: 

Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                13-MAY-2019 08:04:40
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 15 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/network/log/listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.10.10.29)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

initXE.ora:
DB_NAME=XE
DB_BLOCK_SIZE=8192
CONTROL_FILES=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/dbs/control1.ora
UNDO_TABLESPACE=undotbs
UNDO_MANAGEMENT=AUTO
SGA_TARGET=500M
PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET=100M
LOG_BUFFER=5242880
DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/dbs
DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE=2G
ADR_BASE=/wysheid/diag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ora-600 errors are internal errors. They usually tell you that you should contact the Oracle support (if you have an MOS account). On MOS you could lookup the error arguments, but this lookup not always returns a result. Without MOS access the situation could get less comfortable, since Oracle 10.2.0.1 is far beyond support.

But in the given case, you could be lucky, since http://amit7oracledba.blogspot.com/2013/07/ora-00600-internal-error-code-arguments.html claims that the error results from a mismatch in naming resolution and could be fixed with a change in /etc/hosts.